# Crystal Report - How To show details data as a single string in header text field

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

I have crystal report with details fields and header section.
How to show details field's one column data as a single string in header section text field.
I am using Crystal report 2008.

Sample Details Section data :

+--------+-----+
|  Task  | Ref |
+--------+-----+
| Task-A |  20 |
| Task-B |  22 |
| Task-C |  44 |
+--------+-----+

Header Text field need to display reference ID : **202244**

How can I achieve to display the concatenated text from "Ref" Column

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use a subreport in the header section.
Use a formula in the detail section of the subreport to append the data to a global string variable.
Suppress the detail section.
Use a formula in the subreport footer to display the resulting value of the string variable.